# Sum values of attribute when the value of an other attribute is the same

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have an array of objects like this one:

```
{'shapeId': 'shapeid1', 'latlong': '45.42342,-65.23424', 'number': 5}
```

I want the sum of the values of the attribute `number` when the value of the attribute `shapeId` is the same.

Is there a built in method for that? Thank you!

What I tried so far is this, using `reduce()` method, but the results are odd when the function is called many times.

```
    function selectMarkersInPoly() {
        allTotal = new Array();
        alert(allMarkers.length)
        for (var i=0; i < createdShapes.length; i++) {
            for (var j=0; j < allMarkers.length; j++){
                var latlong = allMarkers[j].getPosition();
                if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlong, createdShapes[i]) == true) {
                    allMarkers[j].setOptions({
                        icon : "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png",
                        shapeId:createdShapes[i].id
                    });
                }else{
                    allMarkers[j].setOptions({
                        icon : "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png",
                        shapeId: 'shapeid0'
                    });
                }    
            }
        }            
        allTotal = allMarkers.reduce(function(res, obj) {
          if (!(obj.shapeId in res)){
            res.__array.push(res[obj.shapeId] = obj);
          }else {
            res[obj.shapeId].number += obj.number;
          }
          return res;
          }, {__array:[]}).__array
                .sort(function(a,b) { return b.shapeId - a.shapeId;
          });

          for (var j=0; j < allTotal.length; j++) {
            alert(allTotal[j].shapeId + ': ' + allTotal[j].number)
          }
    }
```

There are 32600 numbers total in allMarkers.number among 3505 objects. The first time I call the function I get:

```
allTotal= [
   Object { number=32598,  shapeId='shapeid0'},
   Object { number=2,  shapeId='shapeid1'}
]
```

where shapeid0 is not selected. The second time I call the function without changing anything, I get:

```
allTotal= [
   Object { number=65193,  shapeId='shapeid0'},
   Object { number=2,  shapeId='shapeid1'}
]
```

And the third time:

```
allTotal= [
   Object { number=97788,  shapeId='shapeid0'},
   Object { number=2,  shapeId='shapeid1'}
]
```

Comment: Clearly the number is going up by 32595 each time. Does that help any?

Comment: Its strange because the total number in allMarkers is 32600 and the selection in shapeid1 is 2. 32600-2 = 32598. Shapeid0 = unselected

Comment: Format your js better, please!

Comment: Im sorry, I dont know what I can format more...

Comment: @Burton449: Try http://jsbeautifier.org/ or similar services

Comment: Your code has blocks that are not properly indented. An inner `for` loop should not be at the same indent level as an outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit oddly formatted. However, the problem is that inside the expression `res.__array.push(res[obj.shapeId] = obj);` you assign the object itself to the `res`, not a clone. With `res[obj.shapeId].number += obj.number;` you then manipulate the *original object*, which is why the results grow in subsequent calls.

Better:

```
var numberSums = allMarkers.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    var id = obj.shapeId;
    if (id in res)
        res[id] += obj.number;
    else
        res[id] = obj.number;
    return res;
}, {});
Object.keys(numberSums).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}).forEach(function(id) {
    alert(id+": "+numberSums[id]);
});
```